# Regex Handle Bars

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this

```
"{{hello}}{{{how}}}{{are}}{{{you}}}"
```

I need to write a regex to only replace the match

```
2 braces followed by anything except {}, ends with }}

{{hello}} is valid
{{{how}}} is not. Because it has 3 braces
```

What I tried `[^{}]*{{[^{}]+}}[^{}]*` but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to get only the matches with 2 braces.

---

For example, if I want to replace the matches with empty string.

`"{{hello}}{{{how}}{{are}}{{{you}}}"`

should become

`"{{{how}}}{{{you}}}"`

Comment: What is the replacement?

Comment: `(?:^|[^{])(\{\{[^{}]*\}\})(?!\})`

Comment: for now lets say "" an empty string

Comment: @AvinashRaj That regex matches an extra } after how. https://regex101.com/r/zK8tU7/1

Comment: @UmaKanth: It does not matter, it is in a capture group.

Comment: `{{{how}}}` doesn't appear in the original. It's not clear whether you want to replace the `{{how}}` that does appear.

Comment: @ChrisLear It was a typo. It should be `{{{how}}}`.  It should not be replaced.

Answer (score 4):

```js
alert("{{hello}}{{{how}}}{{are}}{{{you}}}".replace(/(^|[^{])\{\{[^{}]*\}\}(?!\})/g, "$1"))
```

The above regex should match  the string which was surrounded by exactly two curly braces.

- `(^|[^{])` should capture start of the line or any character but not of curly brace.
- `\{\{[^{}]*\}\}` matches a double curly braced blocks which looks like `{{foo}}`, `{{bar foo bar}}`
- `(?!\})` Negative lookahead which asserts that the match won't be followed by a closing curly brace.

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bA9uH1/1)

Comment: `"{{hello}}{{{how}}}{{are}}{{{you}}}".replace(/(^|[^{])\{\{[^{}]*\}\}(?!\})/g, "")` is giving `{{{how}}{{{you}}}` instead of `{{{how}}}{{{you}}}`. There is an extra match of `}`. https://regex101.com/r/zK8tU7/2

Comment: @UmaKanth You should give `$1` in the replacement part which captures the previous `}`.

Comment: Okay. But it doesn't work in some scenarios like `{{{hello}}}{{how}}{{are}}{{{you}}}`.

Comment: @UmaKanth run an another replace on the output using the above same regex. like `str.replace(regex).replace(regex);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
/(\B|[^{]){{[^{}]*}}(?!})/g
```

And replace with `$1`, see this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iO7eY6/1).

The point here is that the `{{...}}` that is in the middle of the string should be matched if it is either preceded with a non-word character/start of string (`\B`) or not a `{` character (`[^{]`). Otherwise, consecutive matches won't be found.

JS demo:

```js
var re = /(\B|[^{]){{[^{}]*}}(?!})/g; 
var str = '{{hello}}{{{how}}}{{are}}{{{you}}}\n{{{hello}}}{{how}}{{are}}{{{you}}}';
document.body.innerHTML += "----- Input ------<br/>" + str.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>");
var result = str.replace(re, '$1');
document.body.innerHTML += "<br/>----- Result ------<br/>" + result.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>");
```

**UPDATE**

Here is another option for mimicking a negative lookbehind:

```js
var str = '{{hello}}{{{how}}}{{are}}{{{you}}}\n{{{hello}}}{{how}}{{are}}{{{you}}}';
var output = str.replace(/({)?{{[^{}]*}}(?!})/g, function($0, $1){
 return $1 ? $0 : 'x';
});
document.body.innerHTML = output.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>");
```

If there is a `{` before `{{` it is captured into Group 1 and inside a callback, we check if it was matched. If it was, just put back the whole match, else, only replace the match found.